# Forticlient does not appear in "Show Applications" Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, vpn

So my company asked to change vpn to forticlient.
They provided us with a .deb file.
I tried installing via three ways:

`sudo dpkg -i forticlient.deb`

`sudo apt-get install forticlient.deb`

And finally clicking on the .deb file.

All of these ways installs the application with no visible errors/warnings.

But the issue here is the application does not appear under "Show Applications".
Running in cli only works via `$sudo forticlient` and after logging it gets stuck on connecting.

[image: Forticlient Connecting]

I have a VM with Ubuntu 20.04 and installed the same forticlient package, it connected correctly and shows under "Show Applications".

The .desktop files are correctly configured in /usr/share/applications/ .
I assumed so by comparing the files in my VM installation (that is working) and my native Ubuntu installation (that does not work) and the file content is the same.

Also the forticlient installation is in /opt
And there is a symlink in `/usr/bin/forticlient` -> `/opt/forticlient/gui/FortiClient-linux-x64/FortiClient`

My main problem is obviously not being able to connect, but i'm making an association between the forticlient not appearing in "Show Applications" and not being able to connect.

Am i missing something?

Thanks for the help

Things that i tried after creating this post:

- After the forticlient is launched in sudo, can't add it to favorites in the dock

---

```
$ dpkg -L forticlient | grep desktop
/usr/share/applications/forticlient.desktop
/usr/share/applications/forticlient-register.desktop 
/opt/forticlient/Fortitray.desktop
/opt/forticlient/Fortivpn.desktop
```

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/forticlient.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=FortiClient
GenericName=Security Software
Comment=Endpoint Protection Suite
Exec=/opt/forticlient/gui/FortiClient-linux-x64/FortiClient
Icon=forticlient
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
```

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -L forticlient | grep desktop`?

Comment: @N0rbert 
`
/usr/share/applications/forticlient.desktop
/usr/share/applications/forticlient-register.desktop
/opt/forticlient/Fortitray.desktop
/opt/forticlient/Fortivpn.desktop
`

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `cat /usr/share/applications/forticlient.desktop` to it.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it, the application shows up now.
And i can correctly connect now.
Not sure if this solution is ideal/secure?

Solution:

`$ sudo chmod 0755 /opt`

log out and log in, and the app showed up.

I saw the permissions on my VM and realized they were different than on my native installation.

Thanks for the help!